# Vimtex conceal not working properly

Tags: conceal, syntax

Hi I am seeing the following on my .tex files.

[image: Notice the light blue boxes.]

My .vimrc file looks like this

```
let mapleader =" "

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:vimtex_view_method='zathura'
let g:vimtex_quickfix_mode=0
set conceallevel=1
let g:tex_conceal='abdmg'

Plug 'SirVer/Ultisnips'
let g:UltiSnipsExpandTrigger = '<tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpForwardTrigger = '<tab>'
let g:UltiSnipsJumpBackwardTrigger = '<s-tab>'
Plug 'junegunn/goyo.vim'
call plug#end()

set nocompatible
filetype plugin on
set encoding=utf-8
set number relativenumber

set wildmode=longest,list,full

autocmd fileType * setlocal formatoptions-=c formatoptions-=r formatoptions-=o

map <leader>f :Goyo \| set linebreak<CR>

map <leader>o :setlocal spell! spelllang=en_uk<CR>

set splitbelow splitright

map <C-h> <C-w>h
map <C-j> <C-w>j
map <C-k> <C-w>k
map <C-l> <C-w>l

autocmd VimLeave *.tex !texclear % 

map <C-v> "+P`
```

I am also using pywal so maybe there is an incompatibility with that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: please describe what your problem is correctly. According to your screenshot, conceal seems to be working. Also, what exactly is pywal?

Comment: Yes the functionality is working, but I would like those grey boxes to disappear. Pywal is a command that automatically sets terminal colours according to your wallpaper.

Comment: Apologies for being unclear.

Comment: Adjust the Conceal highlighting group to taste (or use conceallevel=2)

Answer (score 3):

try: `hi clear Conceal` at the bottom of your vimrc.

Comment: Welcome to this site! We encourage our users to write answers with justifications to make sure that their answers benefits to everyone, especially new Vimmer with few experience: Here it would be helpful to explain what your command does and why you think that resetting the `Conceal` highlighting group would solve OP's issue. You can use the 'edit' button to add these details.

Comment: Following up on the comment from @statox, using [edit] to build on your answer is a great tool to help communicate to the site's users!